# Selection based on finding 2 different words in 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba, search, match, multiple-columns

I would like to do the following using Excel VBA:

1) look for a certain word_1 within a column;

2) if word_1 was found in step (1), go one column to the right and look for another word which is called word_2. If word_2 was found as well, delete the entire row.

If on the other hand, word_2 was not found, the row does not have to be deleted.

The general idea is to search for multiple words in one column and if they are found, also double-check (for safety) if certain affiliated words are in column 2. Only then the entire rows should be deleted.

I made the following little example for testing:

```
Col1 Col2

xxx xxx
xxx xxx
xxx xxx
findme  acg
xxx xxx
findme  xxx
```

In this example I am searching for the word "findme" in column 1 and for the associated word "acg" in column 2. As you can see, row 4 would have to be deleted because both words occur in one row, as opposed to e.g. row 6, where this is not the case.

My final code:

```
    Sub xxx()

    Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range, aSave As String

    Dim fndOne As String, fndTwo As String
    fndOne = "findme"
    fndTwo = "acg"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ws

        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=fndOne, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

            aSave = aCell.Address

            Do

                If LCase(.Cells(aCell.row, 2).Value) Like Chr(42) & fndTwo & Chr(42) Then

                    If bCell Is Nothing Then
                        Set bCell = .Range("A" & aCell.row)
                    Else
                        Set bCell = Union(bCell, .Range("A" & aCell.row))
                    End If

                End If

                Set aCell = .Columns(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

            Loop Until aCell.Address = aSave

        End If

        Set aCell = Nothing
        If Not bCell Is Nothing Then bCell.EntireRow.Delete


    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: From your narrative I cannot be sure whether the .Find method's `lookat:=xlPart` was intentional. Are you looking to match any part of the search strings or cells containing the whole word(s)?

Comment: @Jeeped yes any part, that was by intention. Sorry the example did not show that

Comment: I've wrapped all of the search criteria in asterisks (ASCII character 0042) and changed `xlWhole` to `xlPart` to accommodate the wildcard searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) and [Range.FindNext method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx), deleting as you go and checking for matching records after each deletion, you should be able to loop through the possibilities quickly.

```
'delete rows as they are found
Sub delTwofers()
    Dim rw As Long, n As Long, cnt As Long, rng As Range
    Dim v As Long, sALLTERMs As String, vPAIRs As Variant, vTERMs As Variant

    On Error GoTo bm_SafeExit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Debug.Print Timer

    sALLTERMs = "aa;bb|cc;dd|ee;ff"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   'set this worksheet reference properly!
        vPAIRs = Split(LCase(sALLTERMs), Chr(124))
        For v = LBound(vPAIRs) To UBound(vPAIRs)
            vTERMs = Split(vPAIRs(v), Chr(59))
            cnt = Application.CountIfs(.Columns(1), Chr(42) & vTERMs(0) & Chr(42), .Columns(2), Chr(42) & vTERMs(1) & Chr(42))
            rw = 1
            For n = 1 To cnt
                rw = .Columns(1).Find(what:=vTERMs(0), lookat:=xlPart, _
                                      after:=.Columns(1).Cells(rw + (rw <> 1)), MatchCase:=False).Row
                Do While True
                    If LCase(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2) Like Chr(42) & vTERMs(1) & Chr(42) Then
                        .Rows(rw).Delete
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        rw = .Columns(1).FindNext(after:=.Cells(rw, 1)).Row
                    End If
                Loop
            Next n
        Next v
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer

bm_SafeExit:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

'collect rows with Union, delete them all at once
Sub delTwofers2()
    Dim rw As Long, n As Long, cnt As Long, rng As Range
    Dim v As Long, sALLTERMs As String, vPAIRs As Variant, vTERMs As Variant

    On Error GoTo bm_SafeExit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Debug.Print Timer

    sALLTERMs = "aa;bb|cc;dd|ee;ff"

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")   'set this worksheet reference properly!
        vPAIRs = Split(LCase(sALLTERMs), Chr(124))
        For v = LBound(vPAIRs) To UBound(vPAIRs)
            vTERMs = Split(vPAIRs(v), Chr(59))
            cnt = Application.CountIfs(.Columns(1), Chr(42) & vTERMs(0) & Chr(42), .Columns(2), Chr(42) & vTERMs(1) & Chr(42))
            rw = 1
            For n = 1 To cnt
                rw = .Columns(1).Find(what:=vTERMs(0), lookat:=xlPart, _
                                      after:=.Columns(1).Cells(rw), MatchCase:=False).Row
                Do While True
                    If LCase(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2) Like Chr(42) & vTERMs(1) & Chr(42) Then
                        If rng Is Nothing Then
                            Set rng = .Cells(rw, 1)
                        Else
                            Set rng = Union(rng, .Cells(rw, 1))
                        End If
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        rw = .Columns(1).FindNext(after:=.Cells(rw, 1)).Row
                    End If
                Loop
            Next n
        Next v
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer  'check timer before deleting discontiguous rows
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then _
        rng.EntireRow.Delete

    Debug.Print Timer

bm_SafeExit:
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

By first checking to make sure there is something to delete, some error control can be avoided; you only need to find the entry for the double matching criteria that you know exists.

**Addendum:** Deleting a collection of discontiguous rows is time consuming. The second routine (`delTwofers2`) above was 5% slower that the one that deleted rows as they were found. 25,000 values, 755 random deletions - 3.60 seconds for the first; 3.75 seconds for the latter.

Comment: The code looks great, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me, because I am looking for any part of the words. Thus `CountIfs` cannot be applied, neither the line `If LCase(.Cells(rw, 2).Value2) = fndTwo `. One more thing I wonder: Why do you prefer to delete rows already while looping, as opposed to doing it as a whole at the end, having used `union` of the respective rows before?

Comment: @EDC - I've made modifications for wildcard searches; changed `=` to `Like`, `xlWhole` to `xlPart` and added asterisks for wildcard matches.

Comment: The nature of this procedure is such that it only goes looking for something to delete when it knows that there is something there. While it could be adjusted for optimal performance by gathering the rows and deleting them all at once, there would have to be a good many rows before any performance improvement was noticeable.

Comment: Ok thanks for the information. In my case I am looking for many words and it will be thousands of rows to delete. I will try to merge the codes to create a solution based on `union` (probably in my original post). Maybe you could have a look on it afterwards? :)

Comment: I'll have another look at it but fwiw, I feel that the performance increase of simply turning off screen updating would make a significantly larger difference than grouping the rows to be deleted.

Comment: Interesting! It is slower, I didn't expect that. Thanks for your edited solution, highly appreciated. I will compare it with my edited post now.

Answer (score 1):

This code applies a filter to the first two columns of the used range using your criteria. It then deletes the visible rows:

```
Sub DeleteSelected()
Dim RangeToFilter As Excel.Range

Set RangeToFilter = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
With RangeToFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="find me"
    .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="access granted"
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks that looks fine. However I must do it with many word-pairs and additionally I am thinking to allow multiple words for the variable word_2 next to "access granted". I don't think this is an issue, it would probably just mean adding some loops and arrays. But in general I like the "find"-solutions a little bit more, because I can see more of what is going on in the code.